# How to debug tests in bun.sh and VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, bun

I installed bun.js vs code plugin and have some success debugging typescript files with provided config.
Also able to debug one test file if I set `program:${file}`

But there is no launch.json example how to debug or just run all tests

config that I'm using, breakpoints not always work but so far it's okish

```
 {
      "type": "bun",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug Bun",

      "program": "${file}",// just open *.test.ts file and this line will allow you to debug current test file
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "env": {},
      "strictEnv": false,
      "watchMode": false,
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "noDebug": false,
      "runtime": "bun",
    },
```

Would be cool to make test explorer work with bun somehow too
If someone know how to add a hotkey to restart previous test that would help a lot

Comment: It too would be great to run the one test at cursor position.